# .htaccess redirect with mysql content in url

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I have URL's like so

mysite.com/view.php?id=123

I have changed the URL's to look like this with .htaccess

mysite.com/123/page-title.html

Now, since the "page-title" part wasn't part of the original URL, and is information from a mysql table that corresponds to the id "123", how can I 301 redirect the old URL's to the new URL's ?

Surely there must be some PHP involved, but I don't know how to write that in .htaccess...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now, since the "page-title" part wasn't part of the original URL, and is information from a mysql table that corresponds to the id "123", how can I 301 redirect the old URL's to the new URL's ?

The only rewrite rules you need is to make the nicer looking URL route to `view.php`, which it sounds like you've already got. Probably looks something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENANE} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([^/]+)\.html /view.php?id=$1 [L]
```

When that request gets to `view.php` you can check the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable, and it will look like `'/123/page-title.html'`. When you see that, you know just to serve the content and be done with it.

However, when the `view.php` looks at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and it looks like `'/view.php?id=123'`, then you know someone has requested the page `http://mysite.com/view.php?id=123` and not the nicer looking URL. When this happens, the `view.php` needs to look up the page-title from the database using `$_GET['id']`'s sanitized value, then create a redirect (all this needs to happen before anything gets printed to the browser):

Something like:

```
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: /' . $id . '/' . urlencode($page-title) . '.html');
    exit();
```

That'll redirect the browser to the page `http://mysite.com/view.php?id=123`. You don't need anything else in htaccess.